# php create thumbnails of images on server

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Could someone help me find out why this function does not work form me.

The parameters given to the function are:
$pathToImages is a full path starting with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$pathToThumbs is an URL which actually is a subfolder called "thumbs" inside $pathToImages

```
function createThumbs($pathToImages, $pathToThumbs) {
    $dir = opendir($pathToImages);
    while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dir))) {
        if (is_file($pathToImages . $fname)) {
            $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
            if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' || strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpeg' ) {
                list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($pathToImages . $fname);
                switch ($type) {
                    case 1: $img = imagecreatefromgif($pathToImages . $fname);
                    break;
                    case 2: $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImages . $fname);
                    break;
                    case 3: $img = imagecreatefrompng($pathToImages . $fname);
                    break;
                    case 6: $img = imagecreatefromwbmp($pathToImages . $fname);
                    break;
                    default:  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImages . $fname);
                };
                $maxWidth = 164;
                $maxHeight = 164;
                if ($width > $height) {
                    $new_width = $maxWidth;
                    $new_height = floor($height * ($maxWidth / $imgw));
                } else {
                    $new_height = $maxHeight;
                    $new_width = floor($width * ($maxHeight / $height));
                };
                $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                // imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                imagejpeg($tmp_img, $pathToThumbs . $fname);
                imagedestroy($tmp_img);
                imagedestroy($img);
            };
        };
    };
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  I have also separated the argument descriptions by using two spaces at the end of the line.

It would help to know how it fails.  Is there an error message ?

Comment: Dear Rohit Gupta!
Thank you for the edit. 
I have found the error: it is a wrong variable name: $imgw  instead of $width.
I spent a day looking at this piece of code, I think I was too tried at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Function looks ok for me. 
Perhaps the directory of the thumbs was not created by PHP User, so your script has no rights to write data in the directory. 
Try to create the /thumbs directory by PHP with

```
mkdir($pathToThumbs);
```

and use

```
chmod($pathToThumbs,755);
```

for giving the correct rights.

Otherwise please offer an error message. ;)

Comment: Dear FlorianR!

I did run the code with "or die" tests after the opendir and every single GD funcion calls - it failed after imagecopyresampled.
A few hours later I found that a wrong variable naming was the problem.
Thank you for your effort!